# jquery append and or html ie issue for dynamic html build

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, nested

I've been going through the other issues posted on this problem but can't seem to match on with my situation. I'm having an issue with jquery nesting elements using .appendTo and .html.  These all work fine in IE9/Chrome/Firefox.  It seems that there is an issue with the bracket closures in the earlier versions of IE, but I'm unable to correct this in my situation.

IE Error Message: **"Error: Unexpected Identifier, string, or number"**

This is a snippet from the larger nest if I can resolve this portion I can replicate this across the rest of the code base.  Debugging stops the JS at the **.html()**

Thanks in advance

```
        $('<li/>', {
        id: lyrVar.liID,
        class: 'layer'
    }).html($('<input/>', {
        id: lyrVar.cbID,
        type: 'checkbox',
        onClick: "chkBox(" + "'" + lyrVar.cbID + "'" + ")",
        checked: lyrVar.chkState,
        name: lyrVar.Name,
        value: lyrVar.val
    })).appendTo('#layersList');
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Do you receive an error message?

Comment: IE breaks on the line and won't run any JS pass this point, specifically '.html()'...."Unexpected identifier, string, or number"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be caused by the unquoted `class` [reserved word](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words) you use as a key in the object you pass to `$()`.

Try:

```
$("<li/>", {
    id: lyrVar.liID,
    "class": "layer"
})
```

Comment: thanks...that was it....wow it seems so obvious now. I looked into the reserved word  definition this morning too.....